# React: How to use ref of a child component in a parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I will explain my self better here, for example i have 2 components 1 will be Modal 2 will be Form.

Modal will have state, functions that it will pass to Form.
Form should have it's own ref. that Modal can use. I try to illustrate:

```
class Modal extends Component {

 handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this.refs.form).form('is valid') {
  //Do something...
  }
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <Form ref="form" handleSubmit={::this.handleSubmit} />
  )
 }
}

class Form extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit} ref={this.props.ref}>
    //Inputs go here...
   </form
  )
 }
}
```

Now the ref we assign in the Modal doesn't work ... we can use the form ref only in the Form component.... how can i share them ??

Comment: why not just to pass `this` into handleSubmit as param? then with ReactDOM.findDomNode you can find it and validate. because your approach is wrong. you can better create HOC and add methods there

Comment: `$(this.refs.form).form` jquery o_O? You can use `e.target` but it kinda breaks encapsulation and such. You should better handle validation inside `Form`

Answer (score 0):

If you really need this:

```
class Modal extends Component {

 handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(this._form._inner.state.isValid) {
   //Do something...
  }
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <Form ref={c => this._form = c} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
  )
 }
}

class Form extends Component {
 state = {
   isValid: false
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit} ref={c => this._inner = c}>
    //Inputs go here...
   </form>
  )
 }
}
```

But you should try to build components with callbacks and do stuff there.

Better try something like this:

```
class Modal extends Component {

 handleSubmit(isValid) {
   //... do stuff
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <Form handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
  )
 }
}

class Form extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
 }

 validate() {
   // ... validate
   this.setState({ isValid: ... });
 }

 onSubmit() {
  const { handleSubmit } = this.props;


  if(handleSubmit) {
   handleSubmit(this.state.isValid);
  }
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
    //Inputs go here...
   </form>
  )
 }
}
```

And you should rly get rid of jQuery if you using React. Bit of overload..